# GIT Repository Migration

Tags: git

I apologize in advance, I feel this is a stupid question :/

I started learning GIT a while back and used it on a few projects. Soon after I backed everything up and reformatted my computer.  Then I made a big mistake by not installing GIT onto my PC for a few months while working on the same projects.  I decided to end my stupidity and reinstalled GIT.  I that my hidden .git folders are still in my project folders.  However, before I start checking out and committing changes, I want to make sure I am migrating properly.  Would I be correct in saying that the visible files I've been working with over the last few months during my GIT hiatus are just files from my most-recently-checked-out branches?  I would hate to checkout a branch containing old files, only to lose everything I've worked on over the last few months during my GIT hiatus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the files in your working copy are (presumably) exactly what they were before you backed up. At this point, all you should need to do is install Git, and then `git` commands will work in your working folders. You'll probably want to start with committing the changes that you have made since you last used Git.

Comment: Okay thank you.  I've read about people having serious issues with a detached HEAD, but never quite understood the concept.  When does a HEAD ever become detached and how do I avoid it?  (...boy that sounds violent)

Comment: A detached head just happens when the HEAD pointer points to some commit that doesn't have any other name (like a branch head or a tag). In your case, even a backup/restore won't change what HEAD points to, so you're fine.